# Java - Importing Physical Fonts

Tags: java, fonts

I've managed to import a new physical font into Java.  I'd like to use my new font on a label, but apparently this isn't possible.  Is there any workaround that will give me a similar result (or better yet, allow me to use it on a label)?

Answer (score 1):

From the javadoc for [Font](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html):

> Applications that require specific fonts can bundle them and
>   instantiate them using the
>   [createFont](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#createFont%28int,%20java.io.InputStream%29)
>   method.

So you can do something like:

```
InputStream is = Main.class.getResourceAsStream('myFont.ttf');
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
JLabel label = new JLabel("My Label Text");
label.setFont(font);
```

Note that "Main" is the name of your class.

Comment: The problem is that Label can't be set to a physical font, or at least so it says:
"Peered AWT components, such as Label and TextField, can only use logical fonts."

Comment: @BIU JLabel != Label. That being said, I do not know if the restriction applies to Swing components also.

Comment: @BIU: Can you just edit your question and post the code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [setTypeface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTypeface%28android.graphics.Typeface%29) method.

Comment: Can you give me some more details please?  I've used `final Font elvishFont = new Font(display, "./assets/fonts/tngan",20,SWT.NONE); ` to get the font, now how should I use the setTypeface method?

Comment: I'm not writing for android, if that makes a difference.  I'm working in Eclipse and I don't see the setTypeface method as an option for any of the components.

Comment: @BIU: See my answer. You just need to do `label.setFont(elvishFont);`

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream is = Main.class.getResourceAsStream('myFont.ttf');
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
ge.registerFont(font);
```

but jdk require > 1.5